# 3rd party library (ng2-page-scroll) not working in Angular-Cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have tried installing "[ng2-page-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll)" into my Angular-Cli project (it uses Angular 2 rc5) but I am encountering an issue after I tried using it in my homepage component:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { PageScroll } from 'ng2-page-scroll'; // this works

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, PageScroll], // this doesn't
  templateUrl: 'homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['homepage.component.css']
})

export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

This is the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll.directive
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll.directive as "./src/ng2-page-scroll.directive" from http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/ng2-page-scroll.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll.directive(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll.directive(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426XMLHttpRequest.send (async)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1515:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll-manager Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll-config Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

From what I understood, it doesn't seem to find "ng2-page-scroll.directive" in "vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/*" but the file is already there.

This is the structure of my files:

- dist/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/ng2-page-scroll.js
- dist/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll.directive.js
- dist/vendor/ng2-page-scroll/src/ng2-page-scroll.directive.js.map

In angular-cli.build.js I have:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'bootstrap/dist/**/*.min.+(js|css)',
      'ng2-page-scroll/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

I also configured system-config.ts:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'ng2-page-scroll' : 'vendor/ng2-page-scroll/ng2-page-scroll.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'ng2-page-scroll':{
    format: 'cjs'
    // defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ng2-page-scroll example, it looks like the code in system-config.ts should be:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'ng2-page-scroll' : 'vendor/ng2-page-scroll'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'ng2-page-scroll':{
    main: 'ng2-page-scroll.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
};
```